# Unusual error when using geom_scatterpie with R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce, scatterpie

I am trying to generate scatterpies with `geom_scatterpie` from the scatterpie package. I am using the example data from [the scatterpie vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterpie/vignettes/scatterpie.html)

```
set.seed(123)
long <- rnorm(50, sd=100)
lat <- rnorm(50, sd=50)
d <- data.frame(long=long, lat=lat)
d <- with(d, d[abs(long) < 150 & abs(lat) < 70,])
n <- nrow(d)
d$region <- factor(1:n)
d$A <- abs(rnorm(n, sd=1))
d$B <- abs(rnorm(n, sd=2))
d$C <- abs(rnorm(n, sd=3))
d$D <- abs(rnorm(n, sd=4))
d[1, 4:7] <- d[1, 4:7] * 3
head(d)
```

this produces the following df.

```
> head(d)
         long        lat region          A        B        C        D
1  -56.047565  12.665926      1 2.13121969 8.663359 3.928711 8.676792
2  -23.017749  -1.427338      2 0.25688371 1.403569 1.375096 4.945092
4    7.050839  68.430114      3 0.24669188 0.524395 3.189978 5.138863
5   12.928774 -11.288549      4 0.34754260 3.144288 3.789556 2.295894
8 -126.506123  29.230687      5 0.95161857 3.029335 1.048951 2.471943
9  -68.685285   6.192712      6 0.04502772 3.203072 2.596539 4.439393
```

when running the same code as in the vignette

```
ggplot() + geom_scatterpie(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=region), data=d,
                           cols=LETTERS[1:4]) + coord_equal()
```

I get the following cryptic error message

```
Error in (function (x, strict = TRUE)  :
  the argument has already been evaluated
```

Is this an incompatibility between `ggplot` and `geom_scatterpie` or `ggforce` and `geom_scatterpie`? 
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I am using R version 3.4.3, ggplot version 2.2.1, ggforce version 0.1.1 and scatterpie version 0.1.0.

Comment: You can try the dev version `devtools::install_github("GuangchuangYu/scatterpie")`

Comment: I did try with the dev version, but it produces the same error. Which version of R and associated packages are you using?

Comment: I'm using `R 3.5.0` and the dev version